# How to send data received on a serial port on Ubuntu (from Intel Edison) to the ethernet port (to another laptop/Server)

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, serial-port, ethernet, intel-edison

I would like to explain my question as specifically as possible:

I am trying to connect Intel Edison board on the Serial port of my Ubuntu laptop and can successfully gather the temperature readings for every 1 second. What I would like to do is connect my laptop to another linux machine (Can be either another ubuntu laptop or a server) using ethernet cable.

I want to send this data that I collect on the serial interface in real time on the ethernet port and see it on the receiving ubuntu laptop/server. How can I do this?

I tried using 127.0.0.1 on my own ubuntu laptop, making it both the TCP/IP client and server to just see if I can get the serial data, unfortunately I ran into some error.

Also, I am not sure which would be my serial port. I have connected two serial ports between my laptop and the intel edison and am not sure which would be my seial port. When I use ttyUSB0 in the commands mentioned above, kit says port/device busy. And when I use ttyACM0 I get the error.

I would truly appreciate all the help I can get on this.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to communicate with the device via a tel type terminal. look in your /dev/ directory for a name similar to your device. If your device is called 'ttyS0' you should be able to do something like `screen /dev/ttyS0` to create a screen that will send your commands over the serial port.

Comment: I have done that. My edison is connected over a serial over usb cable and I can communicate over the serial interface with this device. The port is ttyACM0. I can get the data on the terminal window using screen and read it.

Comment: Where I am stuck right now is trying to send this data over the ethernet port. Just for testing purposes, I try sending this data to the ethernet port to myself using the loopback address. I start listening by:   "sudo nc -lvp 550 > data.txt" on my ubuntu and then "sudo nc 0.0.0.0 550 < /dev/ttyACM0" is the command that I use to send from the serial port to the ethernet port of my own machine. When I do not create the data.txt I dont get any data from the ethernet port and when I do, I get garbage.